# "the next 30 trends in technology of/in the next decade": should this use "of" or "in"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition should be used here, *in* or *of*?

1. the next 30 trends in technology **in** the next decade
2. the next 30 trends in technology **of** the next decade

Comment: Isn't 'the next thirty trends in technology' sufficient? They may or may not occur within ten years.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the sentence makes sense correctly. *Trend* is about what is going on, not so much as what might happen in the future.

Both will work.

That said, there's a significant difference that I see here:

> The next 30 trends **in** technology in the next decade

refers to "trends" (in technology) in the next decade. This uses the term *technology* in the generic sense, extrapolating its development through the next decade.

On the other hand,

> the next 30 trends in technology **of** the next decade

refers to trends in (the) (technology of the next decade). This is about (pieces of) technology specific to the next decade.